# T-SQL: How to use MIN

Tags: t-sql, min

I have the following simple table, called TableA

```
ID  SomeVal
1   10
1   20
1   30
2   40
2   50
3   60
```

I want to select only those rows where SomeVal is the smallest value for the same ID value. So my results should look like this:

```
1   10
2   40
3   60
```

I think I need Group By in my SQL but am not sure how. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, MIN(SomeVal)
FROM [TableName]
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Wrote that but it didn't work because I had another column in the Group By part. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Group by will perform the aggregate function (MIN) for every unique value that is grouped by, and return the result.

I think this will do what you need:

```
Select ID, Min(SomeVal)
From MyTable
Group By ID
```